# Python - urllib2.urlopen - Why do I get garbled characters?

Tags: python, urllib2

Here's my problem:

```
import urllib2

response=urllib2.urlopen('http://proxy-heaven.blogspot.com/')
html=response.read()

print html
```

It's just this site, and I don't know why the result is all garbled characters. Anyone can help?

Comment: The HTML looks fine to me when I request it. It even renders nicely in a browser.  You'll need to be a little more specific about what you mean by "garbled characters".  Can you give us an example of what you expect to see and what you actually see?

Comment: Expect to see: the same as in page source
Actually See: ?       韢kwG茵鐕_1珳D?K汒牌鋩1?x癐v7涖3扚襽fF6嗗靠U誷轭檻%[啇?禩征呼?<~ytW鞘$滿昗o=vご:睫Q彬惜??ZWUN?そ揆IKiM襱边隴\\t/宯弡Н{锉
砮; 彘觓肓禁T甥賢?东h炵眧m杊?$G褁t熏Й夕絶瀟瑙?Q?x繄€壼仞?聼Y慂?毀?=l筢铏?誈荊?矎l'??i鰋莢/~z栽?8/㈣碍听Yp?鈖t?宗絁yi?韆?斄膹?=|s愣le'鴆?稄X蛭殄"燘扐.R%咃?*悱?h肓蝖94哔U>*鐍?醸]?e坝啐楴陇?~黷?厓w嘐掎^?靱?傹漼p?鲇`?矣p祆f檦鳾?暡覬R?N[{箦t鹤啐剭b!?葵6I肶8~膾恺赁4驀?(!军坕菄橌 眸萘$巉羨咤熀??攫覫w4崲x嚽祆v?8菖蹄C*g検泖i淆)d境,;??RS谳?軪z8?鹩羋g?c暧P<霨缌揾:,GF??纞U,н岶#橖W~蠹鹮)蔑s鑙?笜動`?(?麸:枈T???敹v?QmoG? J*x

Don't know why. I should get the source code, don't I?

Answer (score 1):

Without your output it's hard to say but I'd bet it's an encoding issue : this website is encoded in utf8. If your terminal is set in iso-latin for example, it won't be possible for it to display characters properly.

Comment: I've tried several sites with content="text/html; charset=utf-8", which means they are utf-8 encoded, right? The weird thing is all these sites work fine except for this special one:　http://proxy-heaven.blogspot.com/, I really want to know why...

Comment: No, it means the developper have just written it was ; it could be in fact in anything else. The only way to be sure of the encoding is to detect it.

Comment: Well, I'm just starting with python, so would you give some examples on how to decode/detect it? And by the way, everything is fine in my browser using UTF-8 character encoding, does it mean it's UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Sure, there is a great library for that : BeautifulSoup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). I recommand you to set all tour environment in utf8 (your python files, your terminal, ...)

Comment: Would you mind giving me several lines of code on how to make it work all right? I've tried to use BeautifulSoup and html.decode('utf-8') but still cannot get it work.

Comment: If your terminal is setted in utf8, you will want to print html.encode('utf8'), and not decode.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
import urllib
response=urllib.urlopen('http://proxy-heaven.blogspot.com/')
a = response.read()
print a[:50]

> '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Stric'
```

You may have an encoding problem in your terminal, though.

Comment: What can I do to fix it? Weird... I didn't do anything with my python 2.6.5, how come it's not working?

Comment: Well that obviously depends on the platform you're working on, the method of installing python, etc. Does the problem appear in an interactive python session such as the one I pasted above?

Comment: Note, also, that the choice of urllib and urllib2 may make a difference (in your example both were mentioned.)

Comment: Just uninstalled 2.6.5 and installed 2.7, problem remains unsolved. Yes it appears in an interactive python session, i'm using default python shell under XP

Comment: Well, the problem now disappears, and everything works fine. The last minute when I was running the 4 line code it gave me garbled characters, now everything is OK. Weird... Bugging me several hours for no reason

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I suspect it had more to do with the Windows command shell or the the Windows varian of python than with the python code itself.

Answer (score 0):

encoding may be your problem, in which case you want this code.

```
import urllib
s = str(urllib.urlopen('http://proxy-heaven.blogspot.com/').read(), encoding='utf8')
```